# Как убрать дубль главной страницы сайта?

Tags: поисковые-системы, robots.txt, http-status-code-301, яндекс-поиск

В Вэбмастере Яндекса и в поиске Яндекса у моего сайта две страницы. `https://site.ru`
и `https://site.ru/index.php` При переходе по второму адресу(`https://site.ru/index.php`) настроен `301-й редирект` на первый адрес(`https://site.ru`). Но в поиске эти страницы видны обе. Как безболезненно убрать из поиска страницу `https://site.ru/index.php`, чтобы основная при этом осталась? Через Роботс? Через сервис удаления ссылок ЯВМ?

Comment: robots.txt ну ни как не поможет! Яндекс как и другие поисковики не смотрят на него как на первую инстанцию!

Comment: Только исправление ситуации на самом сайте изменит поведение на яндексе!